# running a code after 10 seconds or pressing a key

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++ , I need to create an application to print some thing after 10 second or after pressing a key , I tried this code but it isn't working(after pressing a key it will print "a" lot of a instead of one "a")

```
int i;
while(1)
{
    i=1;

    while(!kbhit()||i<1000)
    {
        Sleep(10);
        i++;
    }

    cout<<"a";

}//while1
```

Can you suggest me any better way?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need the external `while(1)` ?

Comment: while((!kbhit()||Sleep(10)) && i<1000)
    {
        
        i++;
    }

Comment: change the internal `while` to `while(!kbhit()&&i<1000)` because each condition should break the "wait" not both of them

Comment: I need while(1) for print "a" not just one time , I want to print an "a" every 10 sec or after pressing a key ...

Comment: after the first print, you want to wait a again for a new print or always 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't take the first key which was pressed out of the buffer...

```
int i;
while(1)
{
    i = 0;
    while(!kbhit() && ++i<1000)
    {
        Sleep(10);
    }

    if (kbhit()) getch(); // to get the key out of the buffer, otherwise kbhit will keep getting true.
    cout<<"a";

}//while1
```

Comment: In this case first "a" will be printed after 10 sec or pressing key but rest of them will printed only after 10sec , I need all of them be printed after 10 sec or pressing a key

Comment: Well , Now we have another problem , if we don't press any key , app will stop on getch() ...

Comment: @Arashdn - I'm trying to help you while I'm working here on something else... very confusing. now it's OK i think.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code has the biggest problem that it will sleep 10 seconds regardless of if you pressed a key.  Here's my suggestion.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <conio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline int getTime()
{
    return static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int time, totaltime;

    cout << "hit q to quit\n";
    while(1)
    {
        i=1;
        totaltime = getTime();
        time = getTime() - totaltime;
        while(!_kbhit()&&time<5)
        {
            i++;
            time = getTime() - totaltime;
        }

        if (kbhit()) { 
            if(_getch() == 'q') return 0; cout << "you hit a key - hit q to quit\n"; 
        }
        else cout<<"you waited - hit q to quit\n";
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Now what that code does is actually time your code...once it hits 5 seconds, it will display you waited.  If you hit a key other than q, then it will tell you that.  q obviously quits.